# How to add menu item to Material UI Card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, material-ui, card

I have the following example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-card-styling-example-lcup6?fontsize=14

I just wanted to add some menu e.g. Edit, Delete to the 3 dots menu link, but could not succeeded. Tried to add menu items, etc to the `IconButton` and `MoreVertIcon` sections but nothing is changed.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Chico, look at the answer of ckesplin and learn how to reply a question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you have linked does not have any `onClick` action tied to the menu link.  It sounds like you will need a `Menu` element appear when the menu button is clicked.  Take a look at the [Menu component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/) in the MUI docs.

As an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-card-styling-example-with-menu-s9mq6e), I forked your example and added a menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually there is another problem with the mui libraries as they changed their name some years ago. When I try to use the same version, there are other problems in my layout. But I fixed applying some css rules.

Comment: Yeah.  After the update to MUIv5, there were some changes with their styling approach and package naming.  There are some migration instructions if you want to upgrade from v4 to v5.

Comment: By the way I cannot vote up as I have not enough repo :(